# Xunit testing restsharp with Moq

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, restsharp

I'm trying to test my class (se below) in xunit that is supposed to connect to an API and get all customers , the response I paginated. I don't have access to the API how can I mock this in Xunit, I'm using moq and restsharp. What I'm having problems with is creating the mocked responses and setting up the mock. I just need to verify that I get an ok status and and id back

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class TopLevelCustomersClient : ITopLevelCustomersClient
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IRestClientFactory _restClientFactory;
        private readonly string _baseUrl;

        public TopLevelCustomersClient(string baseUrl, ILogger logger, IRestClientFactory restClientFactory)
        {
            _baseUrl = baseUrl;
            _logger = logger;
            _restClientFactory = restClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            string url = _baseUrl + "customers";
            List<string> allCustomerIds = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                _logger.Information("Starting at URL: {Url}", url);

                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                {
                    var client = _restClientFactory.CreateClient(url);
                    var request = new RestRequest();

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(request);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Error getting customers: {response.StatusDescription}");
                    }

                    _logger.Information("Response status: {StatusDescription}", response.StatusDescription);

                    var content = response.Content;

                    _logger.Debug("Raw JSON response: {Content}", content);

                    var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerResponse>(content);

                    _logger.Information("Deserialized response: {ResponseData}", responseData);

                    if (responseData?.TopLevelCustomerIds != null)
                    {
                        _logger.Information("Adding {Count} customer IDs:", responseData.TopLevelCustomerIds.Count);
                        allCustomerIds.AddRange(responseData.TopLevelCustomerIds);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Warning("Missing 'topLevelCustomerIds' property in response");
                    }

                    url = responseData?.Next;
                }

                return allCustomerIds;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78055393/edit) the post to trim it down to a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try [WireMock](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net?tab=readme-ov-file)

```
var server = WireMockServer.Start();

server
  .Given(
    Request.Create().WithPath("/some/thing").UsingGet()
  )
  .RespondWith(
    Response.Create()
      .WithStatusCode(200)
      .WithHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
      .WithBody("Hello world!")
  );
```